# Why "is not a member of package" and "class not found" errors by command line but not by Intellij?

Tags: scala, hadoop, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a Scala test which works in Intellij but doesn't work in the terminal using command line. Code + Errors :

```
[error] ... object Configuration is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.conf
[error] ... object FileSystem is not a member of package org.apache.hadoop.fs
[error] import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}
[error]        ^
[error] ... Class org.apache.hadoop.ha.ServiceFailedException not found - continuing with a stub.
[error]       val hdfsCluster = new MiniDFSCluster.Builder(conf).build()
[error]                             ^
[error] ... not found: type Configuration
[error]       val conf = new Configuration()
[error]                      ^
[error] ... not found: value FileUtil
[error]       FileUtil.fullyDelete(baseDir)
[error]       ^
[error] ... not found: value FileSystem
[error]       val hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
[error]                  ^
[error] ... not found: value FileUtil
[error]       FileUtil.fullyDelete(baseDir);
[error]       ^
[error] ... not found: type Configuration
[error]       val conf = new Configuration();
[error]                      ^
[error] ... not found: value FileUtil
```

Sbt dependencies :

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.6.5" % Test classifier "tests",
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.5" % Test classifier "tests"
```

Comment: to clarify: the test runs and succeeds when you execute it from intellij, but not if you run it via `sbt test`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I get compilation errors in the test. Thank you.

Comment: try writing the test dependencies like this:
`"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.6.5" % "test"`